# Does nock only work if there is an Internet connection?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, nock

I've been having issues using **nock** to test my Redux action creators. When I go offline, I keep getting failed promises meaning the HTTP request using Axios was not successful. When I go online, it works, though.

> So does nock only work if there is an Internet connection?

**Action Creator (uses axios 0.15.3)**

```
export const fetchSomething = (id) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_SOMETHING_LOADING
    });

    return axios.get(`${SOMEWHERE}/something?id=${id}`)
      .then(response => {
        return dispatch({
          type: FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESS,
          payload: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return dispatch({
          type: FETCH_SOMETHING_FAILURE
        });
      });
  };
};
```

**Jest test for the action creator (nock v9.0.2)**

```
test('should dispatch success action type if data is fetched successfully', () => {
  // Need this in order for axios to work with nock
  axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');

  nock(SOMEWHERE)
    .get('/something?id=123')
    .reply(200, someFakeObject);

  thunk = fetchSomething(123);

  return thunk(dispatch)
    .then(() => {
      expect(dispatch.mock.calls[1][0].type).toBe('FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESS');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some issues with using nock to test requests made by axios. There is an [issue in nock's repository](https://github.com/node-nock/nock/issues/699) that discusses that.

I found that [`@supnate`](https://github.com/supnate)'s comment on that issue solved my problem. Furthermore, I had in my code a call to `nock.cleanAll();` inside a `beforeEach()` construct that was the **main culprit** of the problem.

The solution is to remove that. Don't use `nock.cleanAll()`! So now everything works well to test requests made by axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import httpAdapter from 'axios/lib/adapters/http';

axios.defaults.host = SOMEWHERE; // e.g. http://www.somewhere.com
axios.defaults.adapter = httpAdapter;

describe('Your Test', () => {
  test('should do something', () => {
    nock(SOMEWHERE)
      .get('/some/thing/3')
      .reply(200, { some: 'thing', bla: 123 });  

    // then test your stuff here
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `nock` npm module only works in Node and not in the browser. Are you using nock in your testing suite, or as a fill-in for your API while developing? If it is the latter, I don't think the nock middleware will work. You are probably seeing a response from the real API and not the mock api when you are connected to the internet, and nock is not intercepting anything.

If you would like to try a similar adapter that works both in node and in the browser, take a look at [`axios-mock-adapter`](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter)

Comment: I use axios to make HTTP calls in my action creators. For testing, I use Jest and make a call to nock to set up an interceptor. It seems that interceptor is not being used at all. When I go offlline (or call nock.disableNetConnect()), my axios.get fails and goes to its catch block.

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that it has your test case?